# Why is XMLHttpRequest failing the readystate and status state in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi I have this code that for some reasons I don't understand just refuse to work. I really don't know what I will do anymore.
This is my code:

```
<script>
    function findMatch() {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHttp');
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('results').innerHtml = xmlHttp.responseText;
            }else {
                console.log('not ready yet');
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET','aindex.php',true);
        xmlhttp.send();
     }
</script>

     <form>
     Enter a name<br>
     <input type="text" id="search" name="keyword"
     onkeydown="findMatch();"> 
     </form>
     <div id="results"></div>
     //THE PHP FILE TO OUTPUT
     <?php
     echo 'Did it work';
     ?>
```

It prints not ready in the console indicating that the readystate and status test failed. I am working with xamp.
Please pals, any help will be highly appreciative.
Thank.

Comment: Check the Network tab of the console to see if there's any error making the AJAX request.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest goes through several intermediate states before it completes. It's normal for it to print Not ready yet before it's done.

Comment: Your JS is invalid, it shouldn't run in the first place. `document.getElementById('results') = .innerHtml = xmlHttp.responseText;`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Must be a copying error, since he says he's getting console messages.

Comment: You don't have any parameters in the URL.

Comment: that was a typo when re-writing it on stack

Comment: I have a php page as the url, which should echo out an html text

Comment: But doesn't it need to receive the search keyword as a parameter, like `aindex.php?keyword=abc`?

Comment: You have another typo: `statue` should be `status`. Is that in the real script or another copying error?

Comment: yes, but it still wont work, I wonder if its my well I dont know

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors like I said in my first comment? If not, why are you wasting our time?

Comment: By the looks of it if your getting 'not ready yet' it means that the status code is non 200 does your php script give out a non 200 status code?

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the search keyword to the PHP script.

```
var keyword = document.getElementById("search").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET", "aindex.php?keyword=" + encodeURIComponent(keyword)", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

There's also little point in reporting an error when `xmlhttp.state` is not `4`, other states are normal as intermediate steps. If you want to report an error, do it when `xmlhttp.status` is not `200`.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHtml = xmlHttp.responseText;
    } else {
        console.log("Bad status: " + xmlhttp.status);
    }
}
```